# Drywalling my kitchen: any point in "Type X" / Firecode C fire-resistant drywall?

Tags: drywall

all!

I am going to be dry-walling my kitchen. I am eyeing this "Ultra-light Mold Tough" mold-resistant Sheetrock, and next to it "Mold Tough Type C" Sheetrock. Both are 1/2". The latter is about 50% heavier per sq ft. I've opened up chunks of my soffit to try to remove it. Sadly, I was met with an impossibility due to an HVAC supply run that has no alternative path, and unpleasantly positioned plumbing. So, I'll need to cover that up, as well as my exterior wall, which has no drywall at all right now. In the spirit of overkill, I kind of want to get the heavier fire-proof stuff. Is there any reason, besides overkill, I should do that? Any reason not to do it?

It seems much harder to get the Firecode stuff though, Home Depot doesn't even know about it.

Thanks, all!